# Clojure performance for solving Project Euler 72 (counting proper reduced fractions)

Tags: performance, programming-challenge, clojure, rational-numbers

### Challenge

This is a solution of [Project Euler 72](https://projecteuler.net/problem=72) in Java.

> How may proper reduced fractions \$\dfrac{n}{d}\$ are there, where \$n
>  < d \le 10^6\$?

### Code

```
public long solve() {
  int limit = 1000000;
  int[] phi = IntStream.range(0, limit + 1).toArray();
  long result = 0;
  for (int i = 2; i <= limit; i++) {
    if (phi[i] == i) {
      for (int j = i; j <= limit; j += i) {
        phi[j] = phi[j] / i * (i - 1);
      }
    }
    result += phi[i];
  }
  return result;
}
```

The algorithm is explained in detail [here](http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-72-reduced-proper-fractions/). When I run the above code on my machine, it takes 150ms to get the answer.

I translated this code into Clojure like the below.

```
(defn solve []
  (let [limit 1000000
        phi (int-array (range (inc limit)))]
    (loop [i 2 acc 0]
      (if (= i (aget phi i))
        (loop [j i]
          (if (<= j limit)
            (do (aset phi j (/ (* (aget phi j) (dec i)) i))
                (recur (+ j i))))))
      (if (< i limit)
        (recur (inc i) (+ acc (aget phi i)))
        acc))))
```

This code uses Java array and mutate the value within the array. The algorithm is logically the same. However, when I run this code in repl, it takes over 25 seconds, which is a huge difference from the Java solution.

I expected that the Clojure code slightly slower than Java. But this is not a slight difference. Why is the Clojure code is slow like this. Did I miss something? Or is there other way to do this better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(time (solve))

=> "Elapsed time: 27363.381633 msecs"
```

Replace [`aset`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/aset) with [`aset-int`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/aset-int):

```
(defn solve []
  (let [limit 1000000
        phi (int-array (range (inc limit)))]
    (loop [i 2 acc 0]
      (if (= i (aget phi i))
        (loop [j i]
          (if (<= j limit)
            (do (aset-int phi j (/ (* (aget phi j) (dec i)) i))
              (recur (+ j i))))))
      (if (< i limit)
        (recur (inc i) (+ acc (aget phi i)))
        acc))))

(time (solve))

=> "Elapsed time: 443.570909 msecs"
```

This is still three times slower than the Java, but not out of sight.

I thought the original might be using type reflection, but ...

```
(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)
```

... produces no response to the original code.

Answer (score 2):

As per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19573535/2769043) it's super useful to check the generated bytecode for the function as well.

Replacing `/` with `quot` gives a small speed-up as well.

There's also `(set! *unchecked-math* true)` but it's probably wise to be careful with that.

Comment: Unchecked maths looks safe here. Even if it wasn't, It is what the Java does.